# Google Cloud SQL Export without disruption

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, data-analysis

I'm trying to export from a postgres database without causing any disruption to the main server and so far I can see a few ways I might achieve this. The database isn't under huge load (10 req/s), but I don't want to cause any significant disruption. This is for offline analysis so up-to-the-second data isn't a big deal. Which is the ideal way (and which won't work)?

1. Make a read replica of the database, export from that. Worries: does making a read replica cause any major disruption?
2. Clone the database, export that. Worries: does cloning cause disruption?
3. Restore a backup to another instance and export from that. (This is my favourite)
4. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of listed options should cause any noticeable disruption. Options 2-3 are touching independent set of bytes at rest and would be the safest.